# Java Calendar error

Tags: java, calendar

I have some problem with Calendar in Java. When I add weeks to calendar it dosen't work correctly in some cases. Eg. set week_of_yer to 3 and then add -3 weeks ;) works good in most cases but not in year 2010, 2016 etc. (This years are after year with 53 weeks) . It looks like error in JDK, I think they change year when week number is 52 :D Some simple code:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 3);
calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -3);
System.out.println("rolled week: " + calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + " - " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Result of this code is: rolled week: 53 - 2016 :D

Should be 53 - 2015 in all other cases it works as it should.

Does anyone has similar problem?

Comment: Did you consider using jodatime? It's a date handling library which is considered far superior to Java's standard Date and Calendar classes. It also has a way to create a new DateTime a specific Period defined as "3 weeks" from an existing DateTime. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I forgot abut jodatime... it is great library for time.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're showing the *year* rather than the *week year*. You don't need to do arithmetic with the calendar to show this. Basically you're displaying January 1st 2016. The *year* of that is 2016, but the *week year* (i.e. the year within which the week-of-year is calculated) is 2015.

Unfortunately, as far as I can see, Java doesn't have a way of fetching the week year. You'd be best off using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which lets you do all this easily:

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2016, 1, 1);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(date.getWeekOfWeekyear());
        System.out.println(date.getWeekyear());
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
2016-01-01
53
2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon you are right. Today I noticed where is problem it is exactly what you said. I'm interested only in week number and year, so before adding number to week I set day of week to monday. For me it works.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -51);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13536543/642706) is correct and should be accepted. You are confusing week-of-year with a calendar-year versus a week-based-year.

## Week-based Year

If we are talking about the standard ISO 8601 definition of a week, that means:

- Week runs Monday-Sunday.
- Week # 1 is the week containing the first Thursday of the calendar year.

Say that first Thursday is January 2, which means Wednesday the day before is the 1st, and the prior Monday & Tuesday are the last days of the prior *calendar year* but are in the following *week-based year*. So you cannot mix up calendar year numbers with week-based year numbers.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Also, you are using troublesome old date-time classes such as `Calendar` which are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

First get the current date. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `IsoFields`

Get the [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) number by using the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class. And get the year number of the week-based year calendar.

```
int weekNumber = today.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int yearNumberOfWeekBasedYear = today.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );  // Around end/beginning of year, may be different than calendar-year number.
```

Let's take another specific example, the **first day of 2017**. Notice how its calendar-year is of course 2017 but because it lands on a Sunday it is in the last week (# 52) of the **week-based year 2016** (not 2017!).

```
LocalDate firstOf2017 = LocalDate.of ( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 1 );

DayOfWeek firstOf2017DayOfWeek = firstOf2017.getDayOfWeek ();
int weekNumber = firstOf2017.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int yearNumberOfWeekBasedYear = firstOf2017.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );  // Around end/beginning of year, may be different than calendar-year number.
int yearNumberOfCalendarYear = firstOf2017.getYear ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "firstOf2017.toString(): " + firstOf2017 );
System.out.println ( "firstOf2017DayOfWeek.toString(): " + firstOf2017DayOfWeek );
System.out.println ( "weekNumber: " + weekNumber );
System.out.println ( "yearNumberOfWeekBasedYear: " + yearNumberOfWeekBasedYear );
System.out.println ( "yearNumberOfCalendarYear: " + yearNumberOfCalendarYear );
```

> firstOf2017.toString(): 2017-01-01
>
> firstOf2017DayOfWeek.toString(): SUNDAY
>
> weekNumber: 52
>
> yearNumberOfWeekBasedYear: 2016
>
> yearNumberOfCalendarYear: 2017

## Week math

You can subtract weeks with the `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate ld = firstOf2017.minusWeeks( 3 );
```

## `YearWeek`

You will probably want to add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.of( 2016 , 3 ); // Week # 3 of week-based year 2016.
```

Get one of the days of that week by specifying a [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html?is-external=true) enum object.

```
LocalDate ld = yearWeek.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
```

> 2016-01-18

Add three weeks.

```
LocalDate threeWeeksLater = ld.plusWeeks( 3 );
```

> 2016-02-08

Get that new date’s week number.

```
YearWeek yearWeek2 = YearWeek.from( threeWeeksLater );
int weekNumber = yearWeek2.getWeek();
int yearNumberOfWeekBasedYear = yearWeek2.getYear();
```

Generate standard ISO 8601 string representation.

```
String output = yearWeek2.toString();
```

> 2016-W06

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).